# Trouble accessing the right Jquery Selector to change CSS on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, selector

I am having problems accessing the right selector. Currently, on mouseover the ENTIRE grouping of 3 paragraphs gets highlighted not just the one I am mouseover. It should just highlight the 2 elements Title and Content in the paragraph that was mouseover.  Any ideas?

### HEAD

```
$('.leftPanelCarousel').mouseover(function () {
    $('.leftPanelBodyTitle', this).css("color", "#a43802");
    $('.leftPanelBodyContent', this).css("color", "#a43802");
});
$('.leftPanelCarousel').mouseout(function () {
    $('.leftPanelBodyTitle', this).css("color", "White");
    $('.leftPanelBodyContent', this).css("color", "White");
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="leftPanelCarousel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Press</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Press</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Press</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span><br /><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
            <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The codes not coming out that pretty. Apologies.

Comment: You have to wrap every 2 elements 'leftPanelBodyTitle' & 'leftPanelBodyContent' in a container like a <DIV> or something, then target that DIV

Comment: It can't be dont without adding a DIV?

Comment: it can be done with JS, but you should do it via CSS only. JS is not meant for these things, this is why we have CSS...and for that you must change your HTML code. I don't see whats the problem, it's a very semantically bad code anyway that is an abomination to the Internet itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the mouse events to the `li` and then only highlight the spans with in this li using `$(this)`

```
    $('.leftPanelCarousel li').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "#a43802");
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "#a43802");
    });
    $('.leftPanelCarousel li').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "White");
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "White");
    });
```

But as I posted yesterday in an answer to another question of you, this may be also possible with plain CSS for modern browsers.

```
.leftPanelCarousel li .leftPanelBodyTitle, 
.leftPanelCarousel li .leftPanelBodyContent {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.leftPanelCarousel li:hover .leftPanelBodyTitle, 
.leftPanelCarousel li:hover .leftPanelBodyContent {
    color: #a43802;
}
```

## Edit

As I read from your comments you have to modify your HTML, to have it work as you want it to.

```
<div class="leftPanelCarousel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Press</b></span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="leftPanelBodyHeader"><b>Blog</b></span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyTitle">Vivamus consectetur mattis quam</span><br />
                <span class="leftPanelBodyContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit. Nulla ut magna sit. +</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.leftPanelCarousel li p .leftPanelBodyTitle, 
.leftPanelCarousel li p .leftPanelBodyContent {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.leftPanelCarousel li p:hover .leftPanelBodyTitle, 
.leftPanelCarousel li p:hover .leftPanelBodyContent {
    color: #a43802;
}
```

Comment: The extra parameter to `find()` should be unnecessary in your code. AFAIK, `$(this).find(...)` is equivalent to `$(..., this)`. Does anybody disagree?

Comment: @GregL You are right, copy & paste error. I like the `$(this).find()` syntax more.

Comment: Daniel, I appreciate your help as I have been banging my head against the wall trying to work it all out with limited success.

Comment: @CSSHell you are welcome, I'll do my best to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Both of your solutions highlight all 3 paragraphs. Everyone is so helpful, I wish everyones was right!

Comment: Im with @DanielB, I prefer to use .find().

Comment: @CSSHell Okay, you have do define what you mean with `paragraph`. You did not use `<p>` so I was thinking you mean the `<li>` with pararaph. If you mean a combination of one `.leftPanelBodyTitle` and one `.leftPanelBodyContent`, then you have to wrap these two into another container, i.e. a `<p>` or another `<span>` and use this container for hover functionality.

Comment: You rock!   My deadline is tomorrow and I'm fumbling my way to finish line. :)  WITH YOUR HELP!!! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.leftPanelCarousel ul li').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "#a43802");
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "#a43802");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').removeAttr('style');
});
```

But you have a problem with your HTML markup, I believe you have several `'leftPanelBodyTitle'` & `'leftPanelBodyContent'` elements residing under the same `<li>`, so if you split them, this code will work.

Comment: It is dynamically generated <li> and the classes are reused. I need only 1 paragraph color to change, not all.

Answer (score 0):

just call object value $(this) insded of  $('.leftPanelBodyTitle', this)

```
$('.leftPanelCarousel').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css("color", "#a43802");
            $(this).css("color", "#a43802");
        });

$('.leftPanelCarousel').mouseenter(function () {
$(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "#a43802");
$(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "#a43802");
```

}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').removeAttr('style');
});

Comment: All paragraphs are affected.  I just need the one the mouse is over to change color. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line,

```
   $('.leftPanelBodyTitle', this).css("color", "#a43802");
```

`this` points to `.leftPanelCarousel`. So, `$('.leftPanelBodyTitle', this)` selects all the `.leftPaneBodyTitle` inside the div and sets the css.

You need to have something like this,

```
$('.leftPanelCarousel > li').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "#a43802");
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "#a43802");
    });
    $('.leftPanelCarousel > li').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyTitle').css("color", "White");
        $(this).find('.leftPanelBodyContent').css("color", "White");
    });
```

use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) & [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: The above did not have any affect on the color.  It doesn't seem to be selecting the right element.  Same problem I am having. :)